# Confused about exponents and imaginary/real answers

Tags: arithmetic, complex-numbers

I am confused about some exponent behavior.
$$(-2)^{7.6} = (-2)^{\frac{76}{10}} = ((-2)^{76})^{\frac{1}{10}} = ((-2)^{\frac{1}{10}})^{76}$$

Is there something wrong in this logic?  When I plug the different versions into Mathematica, I get complex number for the first two versions, and real numbers for the last two.  And, the last two are opposite in sign.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^y$ is multi-valued unless *either* $y$ is an integer *or* $x$ is real and positive.

In the general case one has to define $x^y = e^{y\log x}$, which inherits the ambiguity of the complex logarithm.

Even for $x>0$, $y\not\in\mathbb Z$, this general definition in principle leads to multiple complex values, but then it makes sense to adopt a convention that real logarithm of $x$ is used. In other cases there is no such common convention -- it isn't possible to fix one convention such that the exponentiation rules always hold anyway.